# what the meaning for 1ahead and 29 lag behind?

Tags: git

When I see my remote tracking branch, I saw the UI shows

1 ahead, 29 lag behind.

I have two files modified, it should be 2 ahead? What exactly does 1 ahead mean?

Comment: We have no idea what UI you are using. `ahead` in the command line usually refers to the amount of commits your local branch is ahead of master, but that could bee completely different here. Please provide more information and possibly a screenshot. Until then, this is a horrible question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*1 ahead* means that you have 1 **commit** ahead of master.